# remove all sub-strings from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I have a string from which I want to remove all possible combinations till the end.
I tried this:

```py
combinations = ['XY', 'ZU', 'YY']
lst_matched = list(filter(lambda val: val in mystring, combinations))
for i in matches:
    if len(mystring) > 0:
        mystring = mystring.replace(i,'')
        print('after', mystring)
```

If I use this with a `mystring` like `ZXYUYY`, it will identify `lst_matched` as `[XY, YY]` and my function will correctly remove these substrings from `mystering`.

However, after removing these substrings, the updated string now has `ZU`which is also another combination to check for.

How can I modify my code such that it searches for all possible combinations till there's no match left? Recurssion could be used but not sure how.

Comment: the ordering of your combinations affects the length of and final outcome: `"ABCDEF" --> [AB, BC, DE] --> "CF"`  whereas `"ABCDEF" --> [BC, DE, AB] --> "AF"`. You have a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def replace(mystring, combinations):
    val = next((val for val in combinations if val in mystring), None)
    while val is not None:
        mystring = mystring.replace(val, '')
        val = next((val for val in combinations if val in mystring), None)
    return mystring
```

Basically you find the first combination that can be found in `mystring` (this can be done with `next((val for val in combinations if val in mystring), None)`). If no such a combination can be found then `val` will be `None`.

Then you replace that specific combination with `''`. And you repeat. You stop when such combination cannot be found anymore (i.e., when `val` is `None`).

Examples:

```
>>> replace('ZXYUYY', ['XY', 'ZU', 'YY'])
''
>>> replace('ZXYUYY', ['XY', 'YY'])
'ZU'
>>> replace('AZXYUYY', ['XY', 'ZU', 'YY'])
'A'
>>> replace('AZBXYUYY', ['XY', 'ZU', 'YY'])
'AZBU'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the replacement until the resulting string is the same as the original string:

```
combinations = ['XY', 'YY', 'ZU']
mystring = 'ZXYUYY'
while True:
    new_string = mystring
    for combination in combinations:
        new_string = new_string.replace(combination, '')
    if new_string == mystring:
        break
    mystring = new_string
print(mystring)
```

Or more simply using a regular expression:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('XY|YY|ZU')
mystring = 'ZXYUYY'
while True:
    mystring, substitutions = regex.subn(mystring, '')
    if not substitutions:
        break
print(mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an "infinite" loop that exits once the string has no occurrences of the strings from `remove_list` (i.e. your `combinations` list)

```
remove_list = ['XY', 'YY', 'ZU'] 

s = "ZXYUYY"
while True:
    if any(i in s for i in remove_list):
        for j in remove_list:
            s = s.replace(j, "")
    break
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the permutations of your "combination":

```py
from itertools import permutations
mystring = "ZXYUYY"
combinations = ['ZU', 'XY', 'YY']
for p in permutations(combinations, len(combinations)):
    for c in p:
        mystring = mystring.replace(c, "")
        print('after', mystring)
print(mystring)
```